# Kubernetes Starting and Stopping Containers Periodically

Tags: docker, cron, kubernetes

I have a set of containers that need to start and stop at specific times periodically. I want to use Kubernetes to manage my containers. I have looked at the Kubernetes documents and I see that there are Cron Jobs. This kind of Job only does half of what I need it to do since my containers will need to stop at a specific time.

I was wondering if there is a way for Kubernetes to start and stop containers at periodic times? If not, is there a work around for me to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have deployment named `nginx`. When you want to stop add cron entry like this.

```
/usr/bin/kubectl  --kubeconfig=/root/.kube/config  scale  --replicas=0 deployment/nginx
```

When you want to stop scale the replicas to 1.

```
/usr/bin/kubectl  --kubeconfig=/root/.kube/config  scale  --replicas=1 deployment/nginx
```

you may have to check the status with `kubectl get deploy nginx`

Hope this helps.
SR

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a cron job to run `kubectl scale --replicas=0 [deployment name]` and `kubectl scale --replicas=1 [deployment name]` if you're using deployments or other scalable resources (replicationcontroller, statefulset, etc)

If you're using bare pods (which you shouldn't ;)), you could do the same but with `kubectl delete pod` and `kubectl apply`